# CKEditor 4.7.3 not utilizing custom config file any more

Tags: ckeditor, config, add-on

I am hoping someone can help me. I have been using CKEditor for years on my production site, ever since FCKEditor, and it has been working very well until recently. I have customized my toolbar and added custom addons and customized the filebrowser and they have been working for a long time. My config file is sitting in a subdirectory but CKEditor just does not want to show the customizations for me, it just shows the FULL toolbar with standard colors etc. Has anyone else noticed this behavior? Is there some fix I cannot seem to find for this? My CKEditor call is below. The odd thing is my dev server and my dev box have no issues with this and ckeditor works just like it should. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
CKEDITOR.replace('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fckTemplateEditor', {
            customConfig: 'ckeditor/myconfig.js'
            , filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'ckeditor/filemanager.aspx?window=' + window.name,
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'ckeditor/filemanager.aspx?window=' + window.name,
            filebrowserWindowWidth: '780',
            filebrowserWindowHeight: '650'
        }, {
            removePlugins: 'elementspath',
            extraPlugins: 'uicolor',
            height: '800px',
        });
        CKEDITOR.config.height = 450;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after trying everything I could find, I figured it out. It seemed it was attaching to the control prior to my replace call so it was giving me an already attached error in the console, which I was not watching for. so I needed to destroy that attachment with the following code and it started to work again. There must be some issue with new browsers and how they work that is causing it to act up and just thought I would share what I found after a day of searching.

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances["ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fckTemplateEditor"]) { // Check null
    CKEDITOR.instances["ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fckTemplateEditor"].destroy(); 
}
```

Thanks